# is there a way to set a default button color (on click) for tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, default

i'm using "activeforeground" in order to make it so that when i click a button the text turns "misty rose." however, i want to apply this to all the buttons in my code without combing through and changing every single one. is there a way to set this as the default "activeforeground" color? similarly to how you can change the default font of text by using this:

```
root.option_add("*font", "times 14 bold")
```

if there is an equivalent for "activeforeground" i would appreciate the help!

Comment: Does `root.option_add("*activeForeground", "misty rose")` work for you?

Comment: hm, for some reason it changes the first button but all the others stay the default

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have a complete [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Also, are you aware that the active foreground only shows up when you hover over a button? The color doesn't stay once you move your mouse away.

Comment: i will add an example, and also i am on a mac, so activeforeground only applies when i click on a button. not when i hover.

Comment: You never added an example. Do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

The name to use with `option_add` isn't always exactly the same as the option used when directly configuring the widget. You need to use the "database name" which typically uses camelCase.

You can get the database name by reading the original tcl/tk documentation, or by calling the `configure` method on the given option. It returns a list of five items. The second item is the name to use with the option database.

In this specific case, you need to use `activeForeground` rather than `activeforeground`.

For more information on what `configure` returns see [What are these strange options returned by the method configure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121451/what-are-these-strange-options-returned-by-the-method-configure/28121752#28121752)

Comment: i am using the proper camelCase, however only the first button is being affected by the `option_add`; the rest of the buttons are still in their default, blue on click, state. should i be using something else instead of `option_add`?

Comment: @user13445224: if you want to set the default option, `option_add` is the way to do it. If you're having problems with more than one widget, you need to update your question with a proper [mcve] that illustrates that.